# Why Appendix appears like Appendix A?

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, verbatim, appendices, layout

I want to create document like this

```
Dedication  
Introduction  
Chapter 1  
      Section 1.1  
      Section 1.2 
            SubSection 1.2.1  
                  SubSubsection 1.2.1.1
Chapter 2  
      Section 2.2  
      Section 2.2 
Chapter 3  
      Section SecThreeDotOne
Outro
Special Thanks
Chapter Extra (Appendix)
Bibliography
```

whit this ToC:

```
Introduction  
1. Cap 1  
      Sec 1.1  
      Sec 1.2 
            SubSec 1.2.1  
                  SubSubSec 1.2.1.1
2. Cap 2  
      Sec 2.2  
      Sec 2.2 
3. Cap 3  
      Sec SecThreeDotOne
Outro
Extra
Bibliography
```

I tried this:

```
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter*{Intro}  
        bla bla bla
    \chapter{Cap 1}
        \section{Sec 1.1}
            bla bla bla
        \section{Sec 1.2}
            bla bla bla
            \subsection{SubSec 1.2.1}
                 bla bla bla
                 \subsubsection{SubSubSec 1.2.1.1}
                 bla bla bla
    \chapter{Cap 2}
        \section{Sec 2.1}
            bla bla bla
        \section{Sec 2.2}
            \ref{sec:extra}
    \chapter{Cap 3}
        \section{SecThreeDotOne}
            bla bla bla
    \chapter*{Outro}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Outro}
        bla bla bla
    \appendix
    \chapter*{Extra}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Extra}
    \label{sec:extra}
        bla bla bla
    \bibliography
\end{document}
```

Why Appendix appears like Appendix A: Extra (I want only the word Extra)?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please add the preamble to your code. Here, it is requested to ask only one question at a time because it makes it easier for other users to search later and facilitates referencing.

Comment: Also, a couple of those questions require lengthy answers and it's too much for one question. Please ask one question per post.

Comment: All of these questions have been asked (more or less) on this site previously.

Comment: Changed, now is one question. I'll try to search. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Check out one of the packages or classes for writing books (as opposed to the more current articles). I'm partial to the memoir class, which has it's very own, detailed documentation (check it out on CTAN). There are others.

To set up a cover page (and the other front matter) is mostly a matter of taste. As opposed to what LaTeX is all about, here *you* have to worry about details of exact placement of text(s), possible images, size/font/... of the title, ... In my experience there is not much help to be had here. Do learn how to use (relative) positioning ($\vspace$, $\fill$ and their ilk).

To set up e.g. page styles, chapter headings, ... memoir has lots of knobs to frob (and you'll even find a book of sorts just of examples in the package MemoirChapterStyles).

Answer (score 1):

Using the `memoir` class solves many of your problems, but you should only ask one question at a time.

```
% doclayoutprob.tex  SE 567590
\documentclass{memoir} % provides headers and footers, but you can define your own
\usepackage{lipsum}  % to provide some text

\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection} % number everything down to subsubsections

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%% A title page
\title{MEANDERINGS}
\author{T. H. E. River \and
        A. Wanderer\thanks{Supported by a grant from the R. Ambler's Fund}\\
        Dun Roamin Institute, NY}
\date{1 April 1993\thanks{Fist drafted 29 February 1992}}
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage

    \tableofcontents
\clearpage
    % possible Dedication
    \begin{center} \textbf{Dedication} \end{center}
    To whom it may concern ............
    \lipsum[1]
    .............

    \chapter{Intro}  
        bla bla bla
\mainmatter
    \chapter{Cap 1}
        \section{Sec 1.1}
            bla bla bla
  
           \lipsum[1-10]
        \section{Sec 1.2}
            bla bla bla
            \subsection{SubSec 1.2.1}
                 bla bla bla
                 \subsubsection{SubSubSec 1.2.1.1}
                 bla bla bla
    \chapter{Cap 2}
        \section{Sec 2.1}
            bla bla bla
        \section{Sec 2.2}
            \ref{sec:extra}
    \chapter{Cap 3}
        \section{SecThreeDotOne}
            bla bla bla
    \chapter*{Outro}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Outro}
        bla bla bla
    \appendix
    \chapter*{Extra}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Extra}
    \label{sec:extra}
        bla bla bla
\backmatter
%% read how to do a bibliography
%%    \bibliography

\end{document}
```

It seems that you know little about LaTeXing documents. Have you read the *Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e* (`> texdoc lshort`)? If not then I suggest that it could be very helpful to you.

Read the `memoir` manual (`> texdoc memoir`) to see what wonderful things it can do for you (warning: I'm the original `memoir` creator).

Comment: Changed, now is one question. I'll open other threads. Thx